# How can I get data from my class sent to my shopping cart

Tags: database, flutter, dart, shopping-cart

I am building a shopping cart for my app using Provider. I can now push data to my cart from my cart model using a list index. However, I'd like to connect information from a class that I've created to the shopping cart instead. I want users to be able to push on each individual product, read about the fine details, then choose to add to cart there. Then be able to return to the list of products displayed in a lovingly crafted GridView.

Here is my cart model:

```
class CartModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  // list of items on sale
  final List _shopItems = [
    // [ title, productPrice ]
    ["Brazil", "15.00", "lib/assets/Brazil.png"],
    ["Colombia", "15.00", "lib/assets/Colombia.png"],
    ["Ethiopia", "15.00", "lib/assets/Ethiopia.png"],
    ["Indonesia", "15.00", "lib/assets/Indonesia.png"],
  ];

  // list of cart items
  final List _cartItems = [];

  get cartItems => _cartItems;

  get shopItems => _shopItems;

  // add item to cart
  void addItemToCart(int index) {
    _cartItems.add(_shopItems[index]);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // remove item from cart
  void removeItemFromCart(int index) {
    _cartItems.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // calculate total price
  String calculateTotal() {
    double totalPrice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
      totalPrice += double.parse(cartItems[i][1]);
    }
    return totalPrice.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
}
```

Here is my cart screen:

```
Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: value.cartItems.length,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.grey[200],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Image.asset(
                              value.cartItems[index][2],
                              height: 36,
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              value.cartItems[index][0],
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              '\$' + value.cartItems[index][1],
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            trailing: IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  Provider.of<CartModel>(context, listen: false)
                                      .removeItemFromCart(index),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              // total amount + pay now

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Total Price',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[200]),
                          ),

                          const SizedBox(height: 8),
                          // total price
                          Text(
                            '\$${value.calculateTotal()}',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

                      // pay now
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.green.shade200),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                        child: Row(
                          children: const [
                            Text(
                              'Pay Now',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                              size: 16,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the class that I'd like to plug into the cart model:

```
class CoffeeItem {
  const CoffeeItem(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.image,
      required this.description,
      required this.image2,
      required this.quantity,
      required this.productPrice,
      required this.unit});

  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String image;
  final String description;
  final String image2;
  final int productPrice;
  final int quantity;
  final String unit;

  Map toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'description': description,
      'price': productPrice,
      'image2': image2,
      'image': image,
      'quantity': quantity,
      'unit': unit,
    };
  }
}
```

And here is the screen where you push the 'add to cart' button, labled here as 'one-time purchase'

```
class BeanScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BeanScreen(this.coffeeItem, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final CoffeeItem coffeeItem;

  @override
  State<BeanScreen> createState() => _BeanScreen();
}

class _BeanScreen extends State<BeanScreen> {
  /*  DBHelper? dbHelper = DBHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<CartProvider>().getData();
  }
 */
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*  final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
    void saveData(int index) {
      dbHelper!
          .insert(
        Cart(
          id: widget.coffeeItem.id,
          productId: index.toString(),
          productName: widget.coffeeItem.title,
          initialPrice: widget.coffeeItem.productPrice,
          productPrice: widget.coffeeItem.productPrice,
          quantity: ValueNotifier(1),
          unitTag: widget.coffeeItem.unit,
          image: widget.coffeeItem.image,
        ),
      )
          .then((value) {
        cart.addTotalPrice(widget.coffeeItem.productPrice.toDouble());
        cart.addCounter();
        const snackBar = SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 113, 52, 255),
          content: Text('Item is added to cart'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        );

        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        print(error.toString());
        const snackBar = SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 56, 110),
            content: Text('Item is all sold out!'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1));

        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      });
    } */

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        title: const Text('Good Vibes Coffee Co.'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CartPage()));
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Badge(
                showBadge: true,
                /* badgeContent: Consumer<CartProvider>(
                  builder: (context, value, child) {
                    return Text(value.getCounter().toString(),
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white));
                  },
                ), */
                animationType: BadgeAnimationType.fade,
                animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20.0)
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Consumer<CartModel>(builder: (context, value, child) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (context, coffeeItem) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 249, 193),
                          child: Stack(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            children: [
                              ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(10),
                                ),
                                child: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage(widget.coffeeItem.image2),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  widget.coffeeItem.title,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 30,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: Text(widget.coffeeItem.description,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18))),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: const [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 50,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(width: 40),
                            Consumer<CartModel>(
                              builder: (context, value, child) {
                                return ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                      backgroundColor:
                                          MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                              const Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 36, 194, 141))),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Provider.of<CartModel>(context,
                                            listen: false)
                                        .addItemToCart(coffeeItem);
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('One-Time Purchase'),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width: 75),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        const Color.fromARGB(
                                            255, 36, 194, 141))),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: ((context) =>
                                            const Subscribe()),
                                      ));
                                },
                                child: const Text('Subscribe')),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: const [
                            SizedBox(width: 80),
                            Text('\$15.00/12oz'),
                            SizedBox(width: 120),
                            Text('\$15.00/16oz')
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(children: const [
                          SizedBox(height: 30),
                        ]),
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried just using `coffeeItem.title` etc. in the list of strings, but apparently, you can't do that. I've also tried to just point my CartModel to CoffeeItem, then tell all of my functions to reach out to that place, but it doesn't like that either.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your provider cart data ,i hope it will help to you

```
final po = Provider.of<CartModel>(context, listen: false);
List<CoffeeItem> cofeelist = [];
Map<String, CoffeeItem > _cart = po. _cartItems();
cofeelist = _cart.values.toList();
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Where do I put this?

Comment: You can put inside start of widget Buildcontext